# CCTiledMap For Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, tiled

How can I add a CCTMXTiledMap on my scene?

I've seen a lot of tutorials for older vesions of Cocos2d. Thank you for any help! :D

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/docs/api/Classes/CCTiledMap.html